# gpgme: selecting a private key when signing data

Tags: gnupg, gpgme

Using gpgme (the development library for gpg/gnupg), I'm trying to sign some data.
In the key ring I have more then 1 private key so I want to select the
correct one.
This fails with: "Unusable secret key (117440566)".
The key was generated with gnupg2 itself. When using gnupg the problem also occurs.

```
sec   1024R/14B7E8E6 2015-05-27
      Key fingerprint = 95C7 6C5E F839 43DA 2F32  2CF4 D2C2 5144 14B7 E8E6
uid                  testkey2 (testkey2) <test@vanheusden.com>
ssb   1024R/ED8059EA 2015-05-27

pub  rsa1024/14B7E8E6
     created: 2015-05-27  expires: never       usage: SC
     trust: ultimate      validity: ultimate
sub  rsa1024/ED8059EA
     created: 2015-05-27  expires: never       usage: E
sub  rsa1024/74D6F5C6
     created: 2015-05-31  expires: never       usage: S
```

First I check if there's a private key for the key selected:

```
gpgme_op_keylist_start(..., ..., 1);
if (gpgme_op_keylist_nex() == GPG_ERR_NO_ERROR) { proceed }
```

do the signing:

```
gpgme_new()
gpgme_set_pinentry_mode(GPGME_PINENTRY_MODE_LOOPBACK) // yes i installed v2.1
gpgme_set_passphrase_cb()
/* ...binary to gpgme_data_t... */
gpgme_data_set_encoding(GPGME_DATA_ENCODING_BINARY)
gpgme_signers_clear()
gpgme_signers_add()   // <- that key that I checked for existance earlier
if (gpgme_signers_count() != 1) { fail(); } // sanity check
gpgme_op_encrypt_sign(ctx, recipient, GPGME_ENCRYPT_ALWAYS_TRUST /* FIXME */, data_in, sig);
```

Now that gpgme_op_encrypt_sign always fails with that "Unusable secret key (117440566)" error.
Any tips/hints?

**Software versions:**

```
gnupg    1.4.18-7
gnupg-agent      2.1.4-1
gnupg2   2.1.4-1
libgpgme++2      4:4.14.2-2+b1
libgpgme11:amd64         1.5.1-6
libgpgme11-dev   1.5.1-6
python-gnupginterface    0.3.2-9.1
```

I enabled debug-tracing but it doesn't help me much:

```
<0x1927>  gpgme_debug: level=4
<0x1927>  gpgme_check_version: call: 0=(nil), req_version=(null), VERSION=1.5.1
<0x1927>  gpgme_check_version_internal: call: 0=(nil), req_version=(null), offset_sig_validity=60
<0x1927>  gpgme_set_locale: enter: ctx=(nil), category=0, value=C
<0x1927>  gpgme_set_locale: leave
<0x1927>  gpgme_set_locale: enter: ctx=(nil), category=5, value=C
<0x1927>  gpgme_set_locale: leave
<0x1927>  gpgme-dinfo: gpgconf='/usr/bin/gpgconf'
<0x1927>  gpgme-dinfo:     gpg='/usr/bin/gpg2'
<0x1927>  gpgme-dinfo:   gpgsm='/usr/bin/gpgsm'
<0x1927>  gpgme-dinfo: homedir='/home/folkert/.gnupg'
<0x1927>  gpgme-dinfo:   agent='/home/folkert/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent'
<0x1927>  gpgme-dinfo:   uisrv='/home/folkert/.gnupg/S.uiserver'
<0x1927>  gpgme_new: enter: r_ctx=0x7fff5afd07a8
<0x1927>  gpgme_new: leave: ctx=0x20c0810
<0x1927>  gpgme_op_keylist_start: enter: ctx=0x20c0810, pattern=0BF38589, secret_only=1
<0x1927>    _gpgme_add_io_cb: call: ctx=0x20c0810, fd 4, dir=1 -> tag=0x20c26b0
<0x1927>    _gpgme_add_io_cb: call: ctx=0x20c0810, fd 6, dir=1 -> tag=0x20c2800
<0x1927>    gpgme:gpg_io_event: call: gpg=0x20c0c10, event 0x7fd8b1a20ad0, type 0, type_data (nil)
<0x1927>  gpgme_op_keylist_start: leave
<0x1927>  gpgme_op_keylist_next: enter: ctx=0x20c0810
<0x1927>    _gpgme_run_io_cb: call: item=0x20c2820, need to check
<0x1927>    _gpgme_run_io_cb: call: item=0x20c2820, handler (0x20c0c10, 6)
<0x1927>    gpgme:keylist_colon_handler: call: ctx=0x20c0810, key = (nil), line = sec:u:2048:1:CC73A8A60BF38589:1433443717:::u:::scESC::::::
<0x1927>    gpgme:keylist_colon_handler: call: ctx=0x20c0810, key = 0x20c2850, line = fpr:::::::::20CD3FF80DA6C1E46CD9F135CC73A8A60BF38589:
<0x1927>    gpgme:keylist_colon_handler: call: ctx=0x20c0810, key = 0x20c2850, line = uid:u::::1433443717::9963CFDE0C8920AD077B06A281992C4008E67E4F::testkey3 (testkey3) <test@vanheusden.com>:
<0x1927>    gpgme:keylist_colon_handler: call: ctx=0x20c0810, key = 0x20c2850, line = ssb:u:2048:1:22317805D48C1491:1433443717::::::e::::::
<0x1927>    gpgme:keylist_colon_handler: call: ctx=0x20c0810, key = 0x20c2850, line = fpr:::::::::FB6FFB7D8BEC710A745DE86C22317805D48C1491:
<0x1927>    _gpgme_run_io_cb: call: item=0x20c26d0, need to check
<0x1927>    _gpgme_run_io_cb: call: item=0x20c26d0, handler (0x20c0c10, 4)
<0x1927>      _gpgme_remove_io_cb: call: data=0x20c26b0, setting fd 0x4 (item=0x20c26d0) done
<0x1927>    _gpgme_run_io_cb: call: item=0x20c2820, need to check
<0x1927>    _gpgme_run_io_cb: call: item=0x20c2820, handler (0x20c0c10, 6)
<0x1927>    gpgme:keylist_colon_handler: call: ctx=0x20c0810, key = 0x20c2850, line = (null)
<0x1927>    gpgme:gpg_io_event: call: gpg=0x20c0c10, event 0x7fd8b1a20ad0, type 2, type_data 0x20c2850
<0x1927>      _gpgme_remove_io_cb: call: data=0x20c2800, setting fd 0x6 (item=0x20c2820) done
<0x1927>    gpgme:gpg_io_event: call: gpg=0x20c0c10, event 0x7fd8b1a20ad0, type 1, type_data 0x7fff5afd0700
<0x1927>  gpgme_op_keylist_next: leave: key=0x20c2850 (20CD3FF80DA6C1E46CD9F135CC73A8A60BF38589)
<0x1927>  gpgme_release: call: ctx=0x20c0810
<0x1927>  gpgme_new: enter: r_ctx=0x7fff5afd0818
<0x1927>  gpgme_new: leave: ctx=0x20c2210
<0x1927>  gpgme_op_keylist_start: enter: ctx=0x20c2210, pattern=4BE78BDCF3F5352CF624A6DF3AD6F8118300CC02, secret_only=0
<0x1927>    _gpgme_add_io_cb: call: ctx=0x20c2210, fd 4, dir=1 -> tag=0x20c1f50
<0x1927>    _gpgme_add_io_cb: call: ctx=0x20c2210, fd 6, dir=1 -> tag=0x20c1fa0
<0x1927>    gpgme:gpg_io_event: call: gpg=0x20c0c10, event 0x7fd8b1a20ad0, type 0, type_data (nil)
<0x1927>  gpgme_op_keylist_start: leave
<0x1927>  gpgme_op_keylist_next: enter: ctx=0x20c2210
<0x1927>    _gpgme_run_io_cb: call: item=0x20c1fc0, need to check
<0x1927>    _gpgme_run_io_cb: call: item=0x20c1fc0, handler (0x20c0c10, 6)
<0x1927>    gpgme:keylist_colon_handler: call: ctx=0x20c2210, key = (nil), line = tru::0:1433443869:2410285847:3:1:5
<0x1927>    gpgme:keylist_colon_handler: call: ctx=0x20c2210, key = (nil), line = pub:-:1024:17:3AD6F8118300CC02:1039074767:::-:::scESC::::::
<0x1927>    gpgme:keylist_colon_handler: call: ctx=0x20c2210, key = 0x20c2b70, line = fpr:::::::::4BE78BDCF3F5352CF624A6DF3AD6F8118300CC02:
<0x1927>    gpgme:keylist_colon_handler: call: ctx=0x20c2210, key = 0x20c2b70, line = uid:-::::1203999932::275AAD3E991F1962AD510CC96760907BE70FE668::Bla <bla@com>:
<0x1927>    gpgme:keylist_colon_handler: call: ctx=0x20c2210, key = 0x20c2b70, line = uid:-::::1203999938::59689891229F1817EF66BFC63D9D0BB2F45F5209::Bla <bla@com>:
<0x1927>    gpgme:keylist_colon_handler: call: ctx=0x20c2210, key = 0x20c2b70, line = uid:r::::::8A709552E7AB85B53DDAE18A48C0978E5EBF5547::Bla <bla@com>:
<0x1927>    gpgme:keylist_colon_handler: call: ctx=0x20c2210, key = 0x20c2b70, line = sub:-:2048:16:942E547C12A6B1C2:1039075030::::::e::::::
<0x1927>    gpgme:keylist_colon_handler: call: ctx=0x20c2210, key = 0x20c2b70, line = fpr:::::::::E69EF5226BBF7EC14F1D7D96942E547C12A6B1C2:
<0x1927>    _gpgme_run_io_cb: call: item=0x20c1f70, need to check
<0x1927>    _gpgme_run_io_cb: call: item=0x20c1f70, handler (0x20c0c10, 4)
<0x1927>      _gpgme_remove_io_cb: call: data=0x20c1f50, setting fd 0x4 (item=0x20c1f70) done
<0x1927>    _gpgme_run_io_cb: call: item=0x20c1fc0, need to check
<0x1927>    _gpgme_run_io_cb: call: item=0x20c1fc0, handler (0x20c0c10, 6)
<0x1927>    gpgme:keylist_colon_handler: call: ctx=0x20c2210, key = 0x20c2b70, line = (null)
<0x1927>    gpgme:gpg_io_event: call: gpg=0x20c0c10, event 0x7fd8b1a20ad0, type 2, type_data 0x20c2b70
<0x1927>      _gpgme_remove_io_cb: call: data=0x20c1fa0, setting fd 0x6 (item=0x20c1fc0) done
<0x1927>    gpgme:gpg_io_event: call: gpg=0x20c0c10, event 0x7fd8b1a20ad0, type 1, type_data 0x7fff5afd0760
<0x1927>  gpgme_op_keylist_next: leave: key=0x20c2b70 (4BE78BDCF3F5352CF624A6DF3AD6F8118300CC02)
<0x1927>  gpgme_release: call: ctx=0x20c2210
<0x1927>  gpgme_new: enter: r_ctx=0x7fff5afd07c8
<0x1927>  gpgme_new: leave: ctx=0x20c2550
<0x1927>  gpgme_set_passphrase_cb: call: ctx=0x20c2550, passphrase_cb=(nil)/(nil)
<0x1927>  gpgme_set_pinentry_mode: call: ctx=0x20c2550, pinentry_mode=4
<0x1927>  gpgme_set_passphrase_cb: call: ctx=0x20c2550, passphrase_cb=0x403420/0x20c0058
<0x1927>  gpgme_set_passphrase_cb: call: ctx=0x20c2550, passphrase_cb=0x403420/0x20c0058
<0x1927>  gpgme_new: enter: r_ctx=0x7fff5afd0768
<0x1927>  gpgme_new: leave: ctx=0x20c0810
<0x1927>  gpgme_op_keylist_start: enter: ctx=0x20c0810, pattern=0BF38589, secret_only=0
<0x1927>    _gpgme_add_io_cb: call: ctx=0x20c0810, fd 4, dir=1 -> tag=0x20c4fd0
<0x1927>    _gpgme_add_io_cb: call: ctx=0x20c0810, fd 6, dir=1 -> tag=0x20c5120
<0x1927>    gpgme:gpg_io_event: call: gpg=0x20c1d50, event 0x7fd8b1a20ad0, type 0, type_data (nil)
<0x1927>  gpgme_op_keylist_start: leave
<0x1927>  gpgme_op_keylist_next: enter: ctx=0x20c0810
<0x1927>    _gpgme_run_io_cb: call: item=0x20c5140, need to check
<0x1927>    _gpgme_run_io_cb: call: item=0x20c5140, handler (0x20c1d50, 6)
<0x1927>    gpgme:keylist_colon_handler: call: ctx=0x20c0810, key = (nil), line = tru::0:1433443869:2410285847:3:1:5
<0x1927>    gpgme:keylist_colon_handler: call: ctx=0x20c0810, key = (nil), line = pub:u:2048:1:CC73A8A60BF38589:1433443717:::u:::scESC:::::: 
<0x1927>    gpgme:keylist_colon_handler: call: ctx=0x20c0810, key = 0x20c5170, line = fpr:::::::::20CD3FF80DA6C1E46CD9F135CC73A8A60BF38589:  
<0x1927>    gpgme:keylist_colon_handler: call: ctx=0x20c0810, key = 0x20c5170, line = uid:u::::1433443717::9963CFDE0C8920AD077B06A281992C4008E67E4F::testkey3 (testkey3) <test@vanheusden.com>:
<0x1927>    gpgme:keylist_colon_handler: call: ctx=0x20c0810, key = 0x20c5170, line = sub:u:2048:1:22317805D48C1491:1433443717::::::e::::::
<0x1927>    gpgme:keylist_colon_handler: call: ctx=0x20c0810, key = 0x20c5170, line = fpr:::::::::FB6FFB7D8BEC710A745DE86C22317805D48C1491:
<0x1927>    _gpgme_run_io_cb: call: item=0x20c4ff0, need to check
<0x1927>    _gpgme_run_io_cb: call: item=0x20c4ff0, handler (0x20c1d50, 4)
<0x1927>      _gpgme_remove_io_cb: call: data=0x20c4fd0, setting fd 0x4 (item=0x20c4ff0) done
<0x1927>    _gpgme_run_io_cb: call: item=0x20c5140, need to check
<0x1927>    _gpgme_run_io_cb: call: item=0x20c5140, handler (0x20c1d50, 6)
<0x1927>    gpgme:keylist_colon_handler: call: ctx=0x20c0810, key = 0x20c5170, line = (null)
<0x1927>    gpgme:gpg_io_event: call: gpg=0x20c1d50, event 0x7fd8b1a20ad0, type 2, type_data 0x20c5170
<0x1927>      _gpgme_remove_io_cb: call: data=0x20c5120, setting fd 0x6 (item=0x20c5140) done
<0x1927>    gpgme:gpg_io_event: call: gpg=0x20c1d50, event 0x7fd8b1a20ad0, type 1, type_data 0x7fff5afd06c0
<0x1927>  gpgme_op_keylist_next: leave: key=0x20c5170 (20CD3FF80DA6C1E46CD9F135CC73A8A60BF38589)
<0x1927>  gpgme_release: call: ctx=0x20c0810
<0x1927>  gpgme_signers_clear: call: ctx=0x20c2550
<0x1927>  gpgme_signers_add: enter: ctx=0x20c2550, key=0x20c2850 (20CD3FF80DA6C1E46CD9F135CC73A8A60BF38589)
<0x1927>  gpgme_signers_add: leave
<0x1927>  gpgme_op_encrypt_sign: enter: ctx=0x20c2550, flags=0x1, plain=0x20c2ed0, cipher=0x20c3f20
<0x1927>  gpgme_op_encrypt_sign: check: ctx=0x20c2550, recipient[0] = 0x20c5170 (20CD3FF80DA6C1E46CD9F135CC73A8A60BF38589)
<0x1927>    gpgme_sig_notation_get: call: ctx=0x20c2550, ctx->sig_notations=(nil)
<0x1927>    _gpgme_add_io_cb: call: ctx=0x20c2550, fd 4, dir=1 -> tag=0x20c2070
<0x1927>    _gpgme_add_io_cb: call: ctx=0x20c2550, fd 8, dir=1 -> tag=0x20c21c0
<0x1927>    _gpgme_add_io_cb: call: ctx=0x20c2550, fd 11, dir=0 -> tag=0x20c2210
<0x1927>    gpgme:gpg_io_event: call: gpg=0x20c1d50, event 0x7fd8b1a20ad0, type 0, type_data (nil)
<0x1927>    _gpgme_run_io_cb: call: item=0x20c2230, need to check
<0x1927>    _gpgme_run_io_cb: call: item=0x20c2230, handler (0x20c2ed0, 11)
<0x1927>    _gpgme_data_outbound_handler: enter: dh=0x20c2ed0, fd=0xb
<0x1927>    _gpgme_data_outbound_handler: leave
<0x1927>    _gpgme_run_io_cb: call: item=0x20c2230, need to check
<0x1927>    _gpgme_run_io_cb: call: item=0x20c2230, handler (0x20c2ed0, 11)
<0x1927>    _gpgme_data_outbound_handler: enter: dh=0x20c2ed0, fd=0xb
<0x1927>        _gpgme_remove_io_cb: call: data=0x20c2210, setting fd 0xb (item=0x20c2230) done
<0x1927>    _gpgme_data_outbound_handler: leave
<0x1927>    _gpgme_run_io_cb: call: item=0x20c2090, need to check
<0x1927>    _gpgme_run_io_cb: call: item=0x20c2090, handler (0x20c1d50, 4)
<0x1927>    _gpgme_run_io_cb: call: item=0x20c2090, need to check
<0x1927>    _gpgme_run_io_cb: call: item=0x20c2090, handler (0x20c1d50, 4)
<0x1927>    _gpgme_cancel_with_err: enter: ctx=0x20c2550, ctx_err=117440566, op_err=0
<0x1927>        _gpgme_remove_io_cb: call: data=0x20c2070, setting fd 0x4 (item=0x20c2090) done
<0x1927>        _gpgme_remove_io_cb: call: data=0x20c21c0, setting fd 0x8 (item=0x20c21e0) done
<0x1927>      gpgme:gpg_io_event: call: gpg=0x20c1d50, event 0x7fd8b1a20ad0, type 1, type_data 0x7fff5afd06c0
<0x1927>    _gpgme_cancel_with_err: leave
<0x1927>  gpgme_op_encrypt_sign: error: Unusable secret key <GPGME>
<0x1927>  gpgme_release: call: ctx=0x20c2550
```

**EDIT**

As requested by @kylehuff, here's the code for the key selection:

```
search_key_result_t gpgme::find_key(const std::string & key_id, const bool priv_key_only, gpgme_key_t *k, std::string *const error)
  {
          error -> clear();

          *k = NULL;

          gpgme_ctx_t ctx = NULL;
          if (!my_gpgme_new(&ctx, false, error))
                  return SK_ERROR;

          gpgme_error_t err = gpgme_op_keylist_start(ctx, key_id.c_str(), priv_key_only ? 1 : 0);
          if (err != GPG_ERR_NO_ERROR)
          {
                  error -> append(format("Problem searching for %s: %s (%d)", key_id.c_str(), gpg_strerror(err), err));
                  gpgme_release(ctx);
                  return SK_ERROR;
          }

          err = gpgme_op_keylist_next(ctx, k);
          if (err == GPG_ERR_EOF)
                  return SK_NOT_FOUND;

          if (err != GPG_ERR_NO_ERROR)
          {
                  error -> append(format("Problem finding %s: %s (%d)", key_id.c_str(), gpg_strerror(err), err));
                  gpgme_release(ctx);
                  return SK_ERROR;
          }

          gpgme_release(ctx);

          return SK_FOUND;
  }
```

Then in the constructor I do:

```
std::string error;
  if (find_key(my_key_id, true, &my_key, &error) != SK_FOUND)
          error_exit(false, "Cannot find key %s: %s", my_key_id.c_str(), error.c_str());
```

and when it is time to sign:

```
          if (find_key(target_uid, false, &recipient[0], error) != SK_FOUND)
                  break;

          gpgme_signers_clear(ctx);
          err = gpgme_signers_add(ctx, my_key);
          if (err != GPG_ERR_NO_ERROR)
          {
                  error -> append(format("gpgme_signers_add(%s) failed: %s (%d)", my_key_id.c_str(), gpg_strerror(err), err));
                  break;
          }

          int n_signers = gpgme_signers_count(ctx);
          if (n_signers != 1)
          {
                  error -> append(format("Number of signers (%d) not expected number (1)", n_signers));
                  break;
          }

          err = gpgme_op_encrypt_sign(ctx, recipient, GPGME_ENCRYPT_ALWAYS_TRUST /* FIXME */, data_in, sig);
          if (err != GPG_ERR_NO_ERROR)
          {
                  error -> append(format("gpgme_op_encrypt failed: %s (%d)", gpg_strerror(err), err));
                  break;
          }
```

@kylehuff, is this what you requested?
Thanks

**EDIT**

Here's the listing for 20CD3FF80DA6C1E46CD9F135CC73A8A60BF38589:

```
tru::0:1433443869:2410285847:3:1:5
pub:u:2048:1:CC73A8A60BF38589:2015-06-04:::u:testkey3 (testkey3) <test@vanheusden.com>::scESC:
sub:u:2048:1:22317805D48C1491:2015-06-04::::::e:
```

**EDIT**

folkert@travelmate:~$ gpg2 --local-user 14B7E8E6 --sign bla.txt

folkert@travelmate:~$ gpg --verify bla.txt.gpg 
gpg: Signature made Thu 18 Jun 2015 07:18:17 PM UTC using RSA key ID 74D6F5C6
gpg: Good signature from "testkey2 (testkey2) "

and with edit key I can see that 74d6f5c6 is indeed the sign sub-key:

sub  1024R/74D6F5C6  created: 2015-05-31  expires: never       usage: S

So I'm a bit surprised that this doesn't work for gpgme.
Not doing the find but directly the gpgme_get_key() gives the same error.

Comment: Could you post the actual code for the `gpgme_signers_add` method and the key selection?  In the debug output you provided, they key selected does not match any of keys listed at the top of your question.  The operation `gpgme_signers_add` is using key "20CD3FF80DA6C1E46CD9F135CC73A8A60BF38589", is that a key you have the both public and private parts, and just not listed?

Comment: Can you please specify which key exactly you are adding? Is it possible that it is sign-only, or encrypt-only? Are you selecting private key or one of the subkey(s) ?

Comment: @NickolayOlshevsky I'm using the key listed at the top: 14B7E8E6

Comment: @kylehuff: that 0BF38589 is also in the key-ring yes but not the one selected. Just before I invoke gpgme_signers_add I call pgme_key_get_string_attr(my_key, GPGME_ATTR_KEYID) and that clearly shows that 14B7E8E6 being selected.

Answer (score 2):

It is difficult to tell what is going on, even with the sample, but here are few possible scenarios -

Something being done in the method `my_gpgme_new(&ctx, false, error)` could be wayward.  What is that function doing exactly?  Why not use the standard `gpgme_new` method?

In the sample provided, you are using the function `search_key_result_t gpgme::find_key()`; is there a need for multiple signers? if so, at least for testing, why not simplify it and just use `gpgme_get_key()`? i.e.

```
  gpgme_error_t err;
  gpgme_key_t key;

  err = gpgme_get_key (ctx, key_string, &key, 1);
  if (err) {
    // .. error handling
  }
  gpgme_signers_clear();
  err = gpgme_signers_add (ctx, key);
  gpgme_key_unref (key);

  int n_signers = gpgme_signers_count(ctx);
  if (n_signers != 1) {
    // .. error handling
  }

  err = gpgme_op_encrypt_sign(ctx, recipient, ....);
```

Additionally with that method, it appears you are adding that method to the gpgme namesapce. Is it possible you trampling on in-built method in the gpgme namespace as well?

As for the recipient object, how is that constructed? It should be a null terminated `gpgme_key_t` structure of `gpgme_key_t`s, even if it is only a single recipient. i.e.

```
  gpgme_key_t recipients[2] = { NULL, NULL };
  err = gpgme_get_key (ctx, recipient_fpr.c_str(), &recipients[0], 0);
  if (err) { // .. error handling }
```

Alternately, if the recipients are provided as an array:

```
  gpgme_key_t recipients = new gpgme_key_t[recip_array.size()];
  err = gpgme_get_key (ctx, recipient_fpr.c_str(), &recipients[0], 0);
  if (err) { // .. error handling }
  recipients[recip_array.size()] = NULL; // null terminate the array
```

Comment: my_gpgme_new is a wapper around gpgme_new which invokes gpgme_new but also invokes gpgme_set_pinentry_mode and gpgme_set_passphrase_cb if applicable.

Regarding find_key: this method searches for a key by any gpgme understood search query. Hopefully this enables people to search by key-id but also by e-mail address.

Namespace: my_gpgme_new and find_key are part of my gpgme class so they should not conflict with the gpgme library (which is plain c afaik).

Comment: For the recipient object: it is indeed an array of 2 elements with the last one being NULL.

To help you people helping me, I've uploaded the code to http://vps001.vanheusden.com/~folkert/gpgme.cpp and http://vps001.vanheusden.com/~folkert/gpgme.h
The finished will be open source anyway.

Comment: Okay, seeing the actual should help, if nothing else, to prevent me from guessing.  Could you also provide the output of `gpg --with-colons --list-keys 20CD3FF80DA6C1E46CD9F135CC73A8A60BF38589` for completeness?

Comment: I'll add it to the original post

Comment: You mentioned in a comment that the method `gpgme_signers_add` is selecting key `14B7E8E6`, but that is not showing as part of the output you amended to your question.  It should be using the primary subkey, which is the only "sign" capable subkey listed.  Where is the subkey with short id `14B7E8E6`?  Is it an expired subkey? (I have seen gpg not display expired subkeys with `--list-keys`)  Can you sign using this key from the cli? i.e. `gpg --local-user 0BF38589 -asr 0BF38589`

Comment: I added a comment to the question with the results of those commands. I'll give you those 250 points anyway for the effort!